# Multiple Checkbox value in Array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have got a form with a table where various student names and other information will be displayed with a checkbox (status) showing in an array.

- The checkbox value is set to 1 or 0 in the table. 1 being active.
- A user will view the info, and if required, disable the entire record by un-checking the checkbox, or re-activate a record by checking the box or do nothing and simply Submit the Form (please see screenshot attached)

All I am trying here is to get the 0 and 1 value so that I can later update the table.

I am getting:

> Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SH - Test\test22.php on line 116
>   Line 116: echo  $status[$i].'';

I understand, that if the checkboxes are not checked it will not be considered. 
I have also tried to use a hidden checkbox with a different id, but couldn’t achieve what I want.

Is there any way I can also accept the value of the unchecked boxes?

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<=$rowcount-1; $i++){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $nominee[$i]; ?></td>
    <td><textarea name="updated_comment[]" rows="4"><?php echo $comment[$i] ?> </textarea></td>
    <td><?php echo $nominator_name[$i]; ?></td> 
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="1" <?php if ($nomstatus[$i] == 1) echo 'checked'; ?> /></td>      
</tr>
<?php }
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $status = (isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '');
    for ($i=0; $i<=$rowcount-1; $i++){
        if (empty($status[$i])){$status[$i] = $nomstatus[$i];}
        elseif ($status[$i] == "1"){$status[$i] = 1;}
        else {$status[$i] = 0;}
        echo  $status[$i].'</br>';
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I have removed the quotes around 1-  (elseif ($status[$i] == 1)

Answer (score 0):

The `Undefined offset` error means that you are trying to access an invalid array position, for example:

```
$myArray[0] = "foo";
$myArray[1] = "bar";

echo $myArray[2]; // This should trigger an undefined offset error, 
                  // as your array has only two positions
```

I would guess that the problem would be related to a wrong reusage of the variable `$rowcount`. I would suggest you to try the following code, where you modify it in order to evaluate the number of elements of `$status` inside the `for` loop.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $status = (isset($_POST['status']) ? $_POST['status'] : '');    
        for ($i=0; $i < count($status); $i++){
            if (empty($status[$i])){
                $status[$i] = $nomstatus[$i];
            } elseif ($status[$i] == "1"){
                $status[$i] = 1;
            } else {
                $status[$i] = 0;
            }
            echo  $status[$i].'</br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, thanks for your reply. Using count($status) in place of $rowcount seems to have resolved the Undefined Index error, but the un-checked checkboxes is still not being considered. Which means it's still not echoing the 0 values.

Comment: When you uncheck the checkbox you are not changing the input value, you are only changing the property checked. In order to submit 0 for unchecked and 1 for checked, you will need to manipulate the inputs. I did a small example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGbJEp), hopefully it will help you.

Comment: Hi Claudio, my logic is working perfectly when I am editing one record at a time. Only issue seems when I am displaying and editing multiple records with array. I will try the JS solution and let you know..

Comment: unfortunately your solution isn't providing the desired result.. I am using a workaround by providing a Edit button beside every record generated, which then pops up a modal window where the user may update individual record. But I would love if there is a solution to do it in the same page...